# failure to parse json array with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I have been unable to parse

```
{
    "Group":[
        {
            "Rssfeed":[
                {
                    "id":"1",
                    "rname":"jamaica Gleaner",
                    "rurl":"http:\/\/jamaica-gleaner.com\/feed\/rss.xml"
                },
                {
                    "id":"2",
                    "rname":"Jamaica Observer News",
                    "rurl":"http:\/\/www.jamaicaobserver.com\/rss\/business\/"
                },
                {
                    "id":"3",
                    "rname":"Jamaica Observer Sports ",
                    "rurl":"http:\/\/www.jamaicaobserver.com\/rss\/sport\/"
                },
                {
                    "id":"4",
                    "rname":"Jamaica-Gleaner News Feed",
                    "rurl":"http:\/\/jamaica-gleaner.com\/feed\/news.xml"
                },
                {
                    "id":"5",
                    "rname":"Jamaica-Gleaner Sports",
                    "rurl":"http:\/\/jamaica-gleaner.com\/feed\/sports.xml"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As I keep getting `nullreferenceexception`  when trying to run the following code:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
JArray jar = (JArray)jo["Group"][0]["RssFeed"];
//loop this
foreach (JObject o in jar.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JProperty p in o.Properties())
    {
        string name = p.Name;
        string value = p.Value.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(name);
    }
}
```

If I remove the `[0]["RssFeed"]` from the JArray I get no a messagebox with RssFeed string, but I am not sure I see why it doesn't work with the full code, is there a better approach to this problem? I am using `json.net` for the first time so maybe I am over looking a few details. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Which line triggers the exception?

Comment: side note, I don't think you need to escape a forward slash in json.

Comment: the code    ["Group"][0]["RssFeed"]; contains a capital 'F', while this is not the case in your JSON.

Comment: Good find @martennis, I will re investigate the suggestion by Jason while I debug some more.

Answer (score 2):

You have a possible case sensitivity issue: your JSON uses `Rssfeed` where your code uses `RssFeed` instead.